# C# indexof is entering if statement when it should not based on the List i have

Tags: c#, string, list

So this should be super simple ,  perhaps  `indexOf` is not the way to go

```
 var incoming = "MDd";  // incoming data


  List<string> cities = new List<string>();
    cities.Add("MD");
    cities.Add("Mumbai");
    cities.Add("Berlin");
    cities.Add("Istanbul");

if(cities.IndexOf(incoming) != 1 ) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("found");
}
else
{
 Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

I am seeing  "found"   with linqpad  output , whether it is correct  "MD" or "MDd"   why? and what do I change to fix this?

Comment: It will never return 1 - if it's found then 0 will be returned, if it isn't then -1.

Comment: ugh,  my mistake ,

Comment: Because `-1 != 1` is `true`.

Comment: @Lee That's incorrect. If it's found it will return the index position of the element. For example if `incoming = "Mumbai"` then `cities.IndexOf(incoming)` would return `1`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - The index of `MD` is 0.

Comment: @Lee Yes, and `incoming` isn't necessarily "MD", it could be "Mumbai", which would return 1.

Comment: @Servy - The question explictly asks about `MD` and `MDd` which is what I was referring to.

Comment: @Lee Then why say, "if it's found it'll return 0 and if it's not then it'll return -1".  If you're just referring to the specific constant "MD" and the exact list shown, then just say, "It'll return 0, since it's the first item" rather than what you said, which implies you're giving a *general* answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typo error.  You want to check for -1 rather than 1 in your if statement:

```
if(cities.IndexOf(incoming) != -1) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("found");
}
else
{
 Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value The zero-based index position of value if that string is
>   found, or -1 if it is not. If value is String.Empty, the return value
>   is 0.

When value is not found in the string, it returns `-1`, otherwise it returns index position, which is greater than or equal to 0. So either check if index is not `-1` or check if it `>= 0`. I personally prefer the latter one:

```
// if (cities.IndexOf(incoming) != -1) 
if (cities.IndexOf(incoming) >= 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("found");
}
```